# modal window show event not working on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am new to stackoverflow, Apologies if it is not in expected format.

Please find below my first attempt on creating a page for one of the small requirement I have. This is a strip down version but good enough to demonstrate the issue.

For each row in table if detail view is expanded ' Show log' is suppose to invoke a modal window show event to get the log message. However if we just expand one row and click show log, modal show event don't get triggered how ever if you expand another row and click show log show events starts working everywhere.

How I can fix this behavior. I am new to web development and have limited Js or Jquery knowledge unfortunately.
Any guidance would be helpful.
Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <title> Show Logs</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .row-index {
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
      var table1_data = [{
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w1'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w2'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w3'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w4'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w5'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w6'
        }
      ];
      var table1_columns = [{
          'field': 'Environment',
          'title': 'Environment',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': false
        },
        {
          'field': 'Workflow',
          'title': 'Workflow',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': true
        }
      ];
      var table2_data = [{
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w1'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w2'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w3'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w4'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w5'
        }
      ];
      var table2_columns = [{
          'field': 'Environment',
          'title': 'Environment',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': false
        },
        {
          'field': 'Workflow',
          'title': 'Workflow',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': true
        }
      ];

      $(function() {

        $('#table1').bootstrapTable({
          data: table1_data,
          columns: table1_columns
        });

        $('#table2').bootstrapTable({
          data: table2_data,
          columns: table2_columns
        });


      });

    });

    function prepare_run_date_table(index, row) {
      var html = [];
      var var_full_json = [{
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log1',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path1',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-30',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w1',
          'index': 1114.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log2',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path2',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-29',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w2',
          'index': 1113.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log3',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path3',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-28',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1112.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log4',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path4',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-27',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1111.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log5',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path5',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-26',
          'Server': 's2',
          'Workflow': 'w4',
          'index': 1110.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log1',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path1',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-30',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w1',
          'index': 1114.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log2',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path2',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-29',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w2',
          'index': 1113.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log3',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path3',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-28',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1112.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log4',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path4',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-27',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1111.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log5',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path5',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-26',
          'Server': 's2',
          'Workflow': 'w4',
          'index': 1110.0
        }
      ]

      var var_env = '';
      var var_workflow = '';
      var var_run_date = 'Run Date';
      $('#logModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {

        var getLogFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
        $(this).find('#logDetails').html($('<p>' + getLogFromRow + '</p>'))
      });
      $.each(row, function(key, value) {
        if (key == 'Environment') {
          var_env = value;
        }
        var_workflow = '';
        if (key == 'Workflow') {
          var_workflow = value;
        }

        html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>');

      });

      html.push('<div class="container">');
      html.push('<table id="tb" class="test" border=1 style="width:auto" >');
      html.push('<tr><th><b>Run Date</b></th><th>Server</th><th style="display:none;">Logs</th><th>Log</th></tr>');
      var counter = 0;
      for (i in var_full_json) {

        if (var_full_json[i].Environment == var_env && var_full_json[i].Workflow == var_workflow) {
          html.push('<tr data-id="' + counter + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logModal"><td bgcolor=#"' + var_full_json[i].Log_File.status + '">');
          html.push(var_full_json[i].Run_Date);
          html.push('</td>');
          html.push('<td>');
          html.push(var_full_json[i].Server);
          html.push('</td>');
          html.push('<td style="display:none;">');
          html.push(var_full_json[i].Log_File.file);
          html.push('</td>');
          html.push('<td>');
          html.push('<u>Show Log</u>');
          html.push('</p></td></tr>');
          counter += 1
        }
        // break after last 7 runs
        if (counter == 7) break;
      }

      html.push('</table>');

      //Modal window code
      html.push('<div id="logModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logModal" aria-hidden="true">');
      html.push('<div class="modal-dialog">');
      html.push('<div class="modal-content">');
      html.push('<div class="modal-header">');
      html.push('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>');
      html.push('<h3>Error Log :</h3>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('<div id="logDetails" class="modal-body">'+' '+'</div>');
      html.push('<div class="modal-footer">');
      html.push('<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      return html.join('');
    } // detailformatter end
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="padding: 10px; ">
    <h1>Runs</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h2>test 1</h2>
      <table class="w3-table w3-striped" id="table1" data-toggle="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" data-height="auto" data-width="auto" data-detail-formatter="prepare_run_date_table" data-show-refresh="true"
        data-detail-view="true" data-id-field="Workflow" data-show-toggle="true" data-tooltip="true">
      </table>
      <div class="footer">
        <p> Click on '+' to see last 7 runs </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h2>test 2</h2>
      <table class="w3-table w3-striped" id="table2" data-toggle="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" data-height="auto" data-detail-formatter="prepare_run_date_table" data-show-refresh="true" data-detail-view="true"
        data-id-field="Workflow" data-show-toggle="true" data-tooltip="true">
      </table>
      <div class="footer">
        <p> Click on '+' to see last 7 runs </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem you describe.  When I click a + to expand a row and click Show Log the modal appears the first time.  Chrome on Windows 10

Comment: modal works but `No Errors!` not appear at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegate event handler and the message would appear at first.

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal','#logModal', function(event) { ... }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <title> Show Logs</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .row-index {
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
      var table1_data = [{
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w1'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w2'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w3'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w4'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w5'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Workflow': 'w6'
        }
      ];
      var table1_columns = [{
          'field': 'Environment',
          'title': 'Environment',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': false
        },
        {
          'field': 'Workflow',
          'title': 'Workflow',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': true
        }
      ];
      var table2_data = [{
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w1'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w2'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w3'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w4'
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Workflow': 'w5'
        }
      ];
      var table2_columns = [{
          'field': 'Environment',
          'title': 'Environment',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': false
        },
        {
          'field': 'Workflow',
          'title': 'Workflow',
          'sortable': true,
          'visible': true
        }
      ];

      $(function() {

        $('#table1').bootstrapTable({
          data: table1_data,
          columns: table1_columns
        });

        $('#table2').bootstrapTable({
          data: table2_data,
          columns: table2_columns
        });


      });

    });

    function prepare_run_date_table(index, row) {
      var html = [];
      var var_full_json = [{
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log1',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path1',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-30',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w1',
          'index': 1114.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log2',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path2',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-29',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w2',
          'index': 1113.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log3',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path3',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-28',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1112.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log4',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path4',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-27',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1111.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log5',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path5',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-26',
          'Server': 's2',
          'Workflow': 'w4',
          'index': 1110.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'prod',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log1',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path1',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-30',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w1',
          'index': 1114.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log2',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path2',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-29',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w2',
          'index': 1113.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log3',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path3',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-28',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1112.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log4',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path4',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-27',
          'Server': 's1',
          'Workflow': 'w3',
          'index': 1111.0
        },
        {
          'Environment': 'test',
          'Graph': 'graph',
          'Log': 'log5',
          'Log_File': {
            'file': ['No Errors!'],
            'status': '00FF00'
          },
          'Path': 'path5',
          'Run_Date': '2018-08-26',
          'Server': 's2',
          'Workflow': 'w4',
          'index': 1110.0
        }
      ]

      var var_env = '';
      var var_workflow = '';
      var var_run_date = 'Run Date';
      $('body').on('shown.bs.modal','#logModal', function(event) {

        var getLogFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
        $(this).find('#logDetails').html($('<p>' + getLogFromRow + '</p>'))
      });
      $.each(row, function(key, value) {
        if (key == 'Environment') {
          var_env = value;
        }
        var_workflow = '';
        if (key == 'Workflow') {
          var_workflow = value;
        }

        html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b> ' + value + '</p>');

      });

      html.push('<div class="container">');
      html.push('<table id="tb" class="test" border=1 style="width:auto" >');
      html.push('<tr><th><b>Run Date</b></th><th>Server</th><th style="display:none;">Logs</th><th>Log</th></tr>');
      var counter = 0;
      for (i in var_full_json) {

        if (var_full_json[i].Environment == var_env && var_full_json[i].Workflow == var_workflow) {
          html.push('<tr data-id="' + counter + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logModal"><td bgcolor=#"' + var_full_json[i].Log_File.status + '">');
          html.push(var_full_json[i].Run_Date);
          html.push('</td>');
          html.push('<td>');
          html.push(var_full_json[i].Server);
          html.push('</td>');
          html.push('<td style="display:none;">');
          html.push(var_full_json[i].Log_File.file);
          html.push('</td>');
          html.push('<td>');
          html.push('<u>Show Log</u>');
          html.push('</p></td></tr>');
          counter += 1
        }
        // break after last 7 runs
        if (counter == 7) break;
      }

      html.push('</table>');

      //Modal window code
      html.push('<div id="logModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logModal" aria-hidden="true">');
      html.push('<div class="modal-dialog">');
      html.push('<div class="modal-content">');
      html.push('<div class="modal-header">');
      html.push('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>');
      html.push('<h3>Error Log :</h3>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('<div id="logDetails" class="modal-body">'+' '+'</div>');
      html.push('<div class="modal-footer">');
      html.push('<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      html.push('</div>');
      return html.join('');
    } // detailformatter end
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="padding: 10px; ">
    <h1>Runs</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h2>test 1</h2>
      <table class="w3-table w3-striped" id="table1" data-toggle="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" data-height="auto" data-width="auto" data-detail-formatter="prepare_run_date_table" data-show-refresh="true"
        data-detail-view="true" data-id-field="Workflow" data-show-toggle="true" data-tooltip="true">
      </table>
      <div class="footer">
        <p> Click on '+' to see last 7 runs </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h2>test 2</h2>
      <table class="w3-table w3-striped" id="table2" data-toggle="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" data-height="auto" data-detail-formatter="prepare_run_date_table" data-show-refresh="true" data-detail-view="true"
        data-id-field="Workflow" data-show-toggle="true" data-tooltip="true">
      </table>
      <div class="footer">
        <p> Click on '+' to see last 7 runs </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: can you explain why it works like this?!